# Animation in iphone using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, core-graphics

I am  very new to animation in iphone . To start with i wanted to implement spinning of earth or globe . how can i do implement it in iphone
thanks  in advance

Comment: can you add more detail on what you'd like to spin, earth is good, but will it a 2D Image or should it be 3D with OpenGL?

Comment: @ Nick Weaver: 2D image will be fine

Answer (score 0):

For 2D animation you would need a number of frames (ideally 360) and then step through the frames in an UIImageView. You can set the animationImages property using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457452/objective-c-uiviewimage-animation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this...this is not spinning but moving image from one location to another

```
CGRect tempFrame=theView.frame;

tempFrame.origin.x=tempFrame.origin.x+50;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

theView.frame=tempFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```